# Program for mixstring

Tags: java

I have written program to mix two strings. For example `string1 =hi` `string2=there`
outputs `htihere` but i am getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str,str1;
        System.out.println("Enter two strings");
        str=scan.nextLine();
        str1=scan.nextLine();
        mixString(str,str1);
    }

    private static void mixString(String str,String str1) {
        String s1,s2;
        s1=str;
        s2=str1;
        int a,b;
        a=s1.length();
        b=s2.length();
        char[] ch = new char[a+b];
        int d=0;
        for(int i=0,j=0;i+j<(a+b);i++,j++) {
            ch[d]=s1.charAt(i);d++;
            ch[d]=s2.charAt(j);d++;
        }
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println( str + str1 );`

Comment: do you want to just concat two input string!! Just use system.out.printlne(str+str1)

Comment: Your code doesn't take into account the fact that both strings don't have the same length. You have to check that i is less than the first string length, and j is less than the second string length. Also, it would be easier to use a StringBuilder rather than a char array.

Comment: @raj did you got your solution?

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is in your `for` loop:

for(int i=0,j=0;i+j<(a+b);i++,j++) {
        ch[d]=s1.charAt(i);d++;
        ch[d]=s2.charAt(j);d++;
    }

Our condition should look more like this:

```
int i=0,j=0,d=0;
for (; i < a && j < b; ++i,++j)
```

This ensures that we only loop through the combining code for as long as both strings have letters available.

We need to declare the iterative variables so they're scoped outside this loop so we can continue where we left off with the longer string:

```
int i=0,j=0,d=0;
for (; i < a && j < b; ++i,++j) {
    ch[d] = s1.charAt(i); ++d;
    ch[d] = s2.charAt(j); ++d;
}
for (; i < a; ++i) {
    ch[d] = s1.charAt(i);
    ++d;
}
for (; j < b; ++j) {
    ch[d] = s2.charAt(j);
    ++d;
}
```

These two loops need to come after the first loop that combines the characters.  At most, only one of these two loops will ever execute, because completion of the first loop guarantees the conditional for one of these two will already return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code was that you were exceeding the limit of the array when the `Strings` `s1` and `s2` had different length. For solving that you check whether i exceeds the limit of the 2 `Strings`.

```
if(i<a){
    ....
}
if(i<b) {
    ....
}
```

I have removed `j` from your code and changed the condition of the loop to `d<(a+b)` as it can be done without `j`.

#### CODE

```
for(int i=0,d=0;d<(a+b);i++) {
    if(i<a){
        ch[d]=s1.charAt(i);d++;
    }
    if(i<b) {
        ch[d]=s2.charAt(i);d++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to do it :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(mixString("hi", "there"));
}

private static String mixString(String s1, String s2) {
    // String writer is good here to avoid dealing directly with a char array
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();

    // Only loop for the min length
    int minLength = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());

    for ( int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        result.append(s1.charAt(i));
        result.append(s2.charAt(i));
    }
    // Add the remaining text of the longest string
    String stringWithMaxLength = s1.length() > s2.length() ? s1 : s2;
    result.append(stringWithMaxLength.substring(minLength));

    return result.toString();
}
```

Don't forget to import java.io.StringWriter. You can also use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this code, works fine on my end:

```
String str = "hellozzz";
String str1 = "dude";
int count1=0,count2=0;
char c[] = new char[str.length()+str1.length()];
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
    if((i%2==0 && count1<str.length()) || (i%2==1 && count2>=str1.length()))
    {
        c[i]=str.charAt(count1);
        count1++;
    }

    else if((i%2==1 && count2<str1.length()) || (i%2==0 && count1>=str.length()))
    {
        c[i]=str1.charAt(count2);
        count2++;
    }
}
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

It will start picking up from the upper defined string and it won't matter which string is bigger or smaller, it will mix it perfectly

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MixString {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s1,s2;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 2 strings");
    s1 = s.nextLine();
    s2 = s.nextLine();

    mixString(s1,s2);

}

    private static void mixString(String s1, String s2) 
    {
        int a,b;
        a = s1.length();
        b = s2.length();
        char[] c = new char[a+b];
        int d = 0;
        for(int i=0,j=0;i+j<=(a+b+1);i++,j++)
        {
            try {
                if(i<a)
                {
                c[d]  = s1.charAt(i);
                d++;
                }
                c[d]  = s2.charAt(j);d++;
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c);

    }
```

}

Comment: Isn't this giving you an expected answer??